# How does Gradle choose between more than 1 versions of the same library in a gradle tree?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, gradle

Let say I have added `Facebook` and `Twitter` dependencies in my app.

> com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1
>
> com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.1.0

When i look at Gradle tree, They come up with bunch of other transitive dependencies.

Now If Facebook uses `com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.1` and twitter uses `com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.3`

Then which version gradle will use.

In gradle tree, It shows `->` in front of older version of dependency. I learnt that this means gradle will use the newer version, and will not use the older version.

But this can be a problem, because some libraries are meant to run on the specific versions, and i have faced this problem.

In one of [article](https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3) i found out how `npm` manages these dependencies conflicts, but i am still unsure how gradle will manage between different version of same library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have different versions of the same library inside an apk.

As you mentioned, by default, Gradle puts the newest one to the build. If you want to specify a concrete version of the library that should be used in your project, you can add a direct `compile` (or `implementation` / `api` for Android Gradle Plugin v3+) statement with a required version to get one.

Also, you can force version using a special syntax, but it can lead to some problems later. You can find more information about version conflicts resolution in [this post](https://blog.mindorks.com/avoiding-conflicts-in-android-gradle-dependencies-28e4200ca235)